# Reputation loan for new users to use sensibly?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, new-users

I am a new StackExchange user and was frustrated to find that the only way to gain reputation at first was to ask a question or answer one quickly. I feel this incentivises new users to post poor-quality answers.

I feel that I have plenty to contribute to scicomp.stackexchange, I just don't have a massive list of new questions to ask.

Can anyone suggest any modifications to the reputation system to aid new users? Perhaps a short-term loan of reputation to perform a few actions - if used sensibly, they get to keep the reputation?

P.S. tried to tag this discussion with 'scicomp.stackexchange' but I need 500 reputation?! Surely this reduces the usefulness of the tags because everyone spams #discussion etc? I redirect you to the question above!

Comment: If you want to ask a meta question specifically about comp-sci, post on their meta site, not the meta site for the whole SE network.

Comment: I was merely citing it as an example - the 'new user problem' is common to the whole of StackExchange.

Comment: Bounty? BTW, "scicomp.stackexchange" is not a good tag – that's why it won't let you add it. You don't have the experience to know what tags are for.

Comment: If that site *isn't* relevant to your question then why would it need a tag for it?

Comment: If you want to contribute to scicomp.stackexchange... then contribute.  You don't need any reputation to do that.

Comment: Re. the tag, okay I get where you're coming from. As for contributing - I wanted to upvote an answer but wasn't able to [Scimonster has suggested a way to slowly gain reputation below in an answer].

Comment: I don't understand this point "*I feel that I have plenty to contribute to scicomp.stackexchange, I just don't have a massive list of new questions to ask.*" If you have so many, just ask them? The entire sentence in of itself sounds contradictory

Comment: @euphoriaoverlord He's implying that he has a lot to contribute in ways other than asking questions.

Comment: Upvoting comes at 15 rep! Ah come on! You can step in and see how easily you can manage to reach that much.

Comment: I will keep trying!

Answer (score 9):

The actions that we want people to be able to perform when they haven't earned any reputation are the actions that people can perform with 1 rep (asking/answering/etc.).  If we wanted people to be able to do actions that have a higher rep requirement without having to earn any rep, then *they wouldn't have those rep requirements*.

Answer (score 2):

What would you do with the reputation, and how would we gauge if you should keep it? And how much are you thinking of?

You can gain reputation -- slowly -- by [suggesting edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing). Each approved one gets 2 rep. After 500, you'd have 1K already. :)

Comment: I'd use it to upvote some answers that I thought were good. You could gauge whether or not the user would keep it by what they do. Positive usage might be upvoting [as it helps sift answers without being overly negative]. Negative usage might be nasty comments etc. P.S. thanks for the tip on edits.

Comment: @GarethMorgan If you can't even make a single post that one or two people think is helpful, what makes you qualified to judge how helpful other user's comments are?  How do we know you'll actually upvote helpful content?  How do we know you won't just upvote your other accounts?  Upvoting is helpful *when you're upvoting helpful content that you're qualified to judge*.  But it's a tool that has a lot of potential for abuse and harm.  Posting a *single* post of even marginal quality is already an *extremely* low bar for that privilege.  Personally I think its *way* too low.

Comment: @GarethMorgan - How would this be judged? Moderators can't possibly judge the tens of thousands of new users we get. How could we prevent abuse of this from people who would create dozens of fake accounts to vote up their posts? How would you stop the spam that would flood the site in comments?

Comment: I'd appreciate a little less hostility. I'm trying to stimulate some debate that might result in a better site. Yes it would be difficult to judge, and largely automatic. I don't have _all_ the answers, after all this is a crowd-sourced answer site.

Comment: @GarethMorgan People pointing out flaws in your proposal isn't being hostile.  When you propose a feature you're starting a discussion.  If people don't think it's a good idea, they'll say so.  In this case you're getting the feedback that people are simply not interested in trying to figure out how to let people do all sorts of things without having earned reputation.  The site was in fact designed with automated ways of determining which users are likely to be good contributors so that those users can have additional privileges; that system is by giving reputation for quality contributions.